# cmd.exe only returning 80 columns

Tags: c#, shell, command-line, process

Here's a handy wrapper I use regularly for shelling command line operations without displaying a window.

```
public static ShellResponse Execute(string command, string args, string workingDirectory, int timeout)
    {
        Timeout = timeout;
        ShellResponse response = new ShellResponse(-1);
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(command)
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args))
        {
            processInfo.Arguments = args;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workingDirectory))
        {
            processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        }
        try
        {
            using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(processInfo))
            {
                if (processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput)
                {
                    response.Output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                }
                process.WaitForExit(Timeout);
                response.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
                process.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

It works fine except for the fact that certain commands are capable of outputting text that exceeds 80 characters per line. This method, however, always returns 80 character-width lines. This, unfortunately, cuts off a good portion of the text. Do you know if there's a way to have the method return the full line rather than truncating it? Or, at the very least, can the width be extended beyond the default 80 characters?

Comment: Does truncation occur when running the same command at a `cmd.exe` prompt, with output redirected to a file?

Comment: And why does your title say `cmd.exe` when it appears nowhere in your code?

Comment: Interestingly, the truncation still occurs at the command prompt but it is determined by the width of the command window at the time of execution. If I execute the command in a standard window and then enlarge the window and execute the command again, I get more characters. That might be a clue. Also, this is a generic shell execute method. "cmd.exe" is passed as the value of the argument "command" in the above code.

Comment: Well, the truncation is not happening in your code.  The only way your code could stop it is by invoking not `cmd.exe` but a helper console-mode process which sets the console buffer size before invoking the final command.  Much easier would be to fix the command being invoked.  Maybe it provides an option for unlimited width lines, or to control the line width.  Check its documentation.